# Is it possible to activate/deactivate or display/hide the properties windows and the toolbox in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I've always wondered if Microsoft ever implemented this feature in their Visual Studio releases.
Basically when I'm designing a form I need to have the toolbox and the properties window active. Conversely, when I'm in the code behind I would like to hide these windows and have only the main window of the code. Yes, I know, there is a specific function that anchors these windows at will and makes them open when you hover over them, but it's not the same thing. I would like these windows to open and close automatically when switching from drawing mode to code mode and vice versa.
Is it possible?